# Updating realm file on Google Drive Api

Tags: google-drive-api, realm, google-drive-android-api

I have a function to upload files to Google Drive.

I tried to upload with a pdf file, It's working.

```
public Task<String> createFilePDF(String filePath){
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor,()->{
            File fileMetaData = new File();
            fileMetaData.setName("DinotesDemo");

            java.io.File file = new java.io.File(filePath);
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/pdf",file);

            File myFile = null;
            try {
                myFile = mDriveService.files().create(fileMetaData,mediaContent).execute();
            }catch (Exception e){
            }
            if (myFile == null){
                throw new IOException("Null result");
            }

            return myFile.getId();
        });
    }
```

And now, I need to upload the realm file to drive. What should I do?

Thanks very much!!

Comment: You have shared code for creating a pdf file. A realm file can be picked from the filesystem and can be uploaded like a normal file. What's the difficulty as such? Are you facing difficulty retrieving the realm file?

Comment: Thank bro. I upload pdf file success because drive support upload pdf file with MimeType = "application/pdf" . But realm file , It need setMimeType = "text/plain" , and convert realm file to something.  It be like the link https://medium.com/glucosio-project/backup-restore-a-realm-database-on-google-drive-with-drive-api-c238515a5975 .

Comment: English is not my mother tongue, please excuse any errors on my part.

Comment: please share the upload code

Comment: I thought the link explains it well. It reads the realm file byte by byte and writes to the OutputStream of DriveContents which is used to write the realm file contents to Google Drive.

Comment: Yes. But this post is very old. And google drive api v3 don't has DriveContents .

Comment: please share your project on a github repo. Will take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/trunghaudinh/demogg.git  . This project is demo, You can find function upload_file in LoginActivity

Comment: You can upload any file with any filetype you want to googleDrive. No need to convert the file to something as that is all done for you. See [Simple Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple) and then note *If the format of the content can't be detected, then the MIME type will be set to 'application/octet-stream'.* and also *Google Drive describes files by types. Blob: A file that contains text or binary content such as images, videos, and PDFs*

Comment: @Jay Thanks very much. I was change MIME type = 'application/octet-stream' and it's working.